# Tests retaining reference count

Tags: objective-c, ocunit

It seems octest doesn't decrement reference count for instances created within a test

```
- (void)test_That_TaskFetcher_is_Invoked_from_tasksDownloaded {
    InboxViewController *vc = [[InboxViewController alloc] init];
    id fetcher = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[TaskFetcher class]];
    [vc setTaskFetcher:fetcher];
    [[fetcher expect] fetchTasksfromManagedObjectContext:OCMOCK_ANY
                                           withPredicate:OCMOCK_ANY
                                    WithBlockForEachTask:OCMOCK_ANY
                                        WithFailureBlock:OCMOCK_ANY
                                      WithNoResultsBlock:OCMOCK_ANY
                                     WithCompletionBlock:OCMOCK_ANY];
    [vc tasksDownloaded];
    STVerify(fetcher);
}
```

vc has a [NSNotificationCenter defaultcenter] listener on it. The listener on this vc instance is getting invoked from other tests.

why???

Comment: Did you set your test target to use ARC?

Comment: Does this happen for failing test, passing test, or both?

Answer (score 1):

...are you removing the notification observer from your view controller? Calls to `addObserver:` need to be matched with a corresponding `removeObserver:`, otherwise you can run into these sorts of issues.

Comment: i'm removing the observer on `dealloc`, but dealloc is never getting invoked

Comment: also, notification center observers are weak references, so it wouldn't lead to retained reference count